# Why is it impossible to pass the string "curve?" to a python script using sys.argv

Tags: python, sys, msys2

First time poster, long time googler.
Ok, I have a workaround for this but, for the life of me, I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

This will not print "curve?" If passed like `python3 script.py curve?`

It prints 'curve'

I've tried

```
python3 script.py 'curve?'

python3 script.py "curve?"`

python3 script.py curve\?`

python3 script.py \curve?`

python3 script.py r'curve?'
```

among many other combinations. It always returns `curve` without the `?` or `curve\ ?`

Here's where it gets weird, it will print different parts of the word correctly.

```
python3 script.py cuve?

python3 script.py cure?

python3 script.py urve?
```

All print correctly but it gets weirder because

```
python3 script.py curv?
```

prints `curve`

Like I said, I have a workaround. But I'm really hoping someone could explain why this might not work. I do have a slightly weird setup so if nobody else can replicate this, I'm gonna assume it's my setup. I'm running from msys64 on Windows 1
0.

Comment: `?` has special meaning to the shell, it's a wildcard character. If you have files named `curve1, curve2`, etc. it will be expanded to those filenames.

Comment: But putting it in quotes should solve that problem.

Comment: both of `python3 script.py "curve?"` and `python3 script.py curve\?` prints `curve?`. `python3 script.py curv?` prints `curve` only if you have a file `curve`

Comment: @Bibhav That was it! There was infact a 'curve' directory. And this makes sense with '?' being a wildcard. Thanks! Was gonna drive me crazy.